# TopShelf install multiple of the same service on the same machine

Tags: topshelf

I am trying to create windows service using TopShelf. Everything works fine with one instance of the service. However, when I copy the whole service folder to a different location and then run the installation at the location it just hangs on "startup".

I assign the servicename, description, displayaname based on the value in a config files so there is no naming conflict.

Comment: Come join the mailing list with this, and include the log output if you can. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/topshelf-discuss. This will be hard to figure out across SO; however, you can set "instance" name that should allow you to run two of the same services.

Comment: Are you sure that servicename AND displayname are unique? Tried installing two services with unique servicenames but using same displayname and it didn't worked too.

Answer (score 31):

It's the service's `instancename` that you need to differentiate.

From the [documentation](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/commandline.html):

> service.exe **[verb]** [-option:value] [-switch]
>
> **install** Installs the service
>
> -instance An instance name if registering the service multiple times

So you could use:

```
service.exe install -instance:FirstInstanceOfMyService

service.exe install -instance:SecondInstanceOfMyService
```

Answer (score 9):

If what you want is to set the service instance name in the config file, you can set the instance name programatically like this:

```
var instanceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Instance"];
HostFactory.Run(hostConfigurator =>
{    
    ...   
    hostConfigurator.SetDisplayName("My service");
    hostConfigurator.SetDescription("My service that does something");
    hostConfigurator.SetServiceName("MyService");
    hostConfigurator.SetInstanceName(instanceName);
}
```

So, during the installation you only run

```
  MyService.exe install
```